# Scene transition troubleshoot in spritekit in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm Trying to make a Start Scene Where you press a "Start" Button, and it goes to the main game scene. Here's the code:

```
if startBTN.containsPoint(location) {

            let gameSceneTemp = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
            self.scene?.view?.presentScene(gameSceneTemp, transition: SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.01))

        }
```

But for some reason, whenever the scene loads up, it displays a squished-like scene in the GameScene. Can anyone help solve this problem by displaying a normal size (portarit) scene? Here's the Screen shots between the expected and actual scene:

[The Expected Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1USOa.png)

[The Actual Scene (The Problem)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKWJX.png)

Comment: Check your scene's 'scaleMode'. Alternatively, posting a screenshot of both the desired and actual screen would help.

Comment: There's a lot of trouble shooting possibles that could cause this. @SteveIves is the man that not only knows most about this, but also has the best communication skills for routing out the problem and fixing it. To give him a headstart.. are you making these in code (the scenes) or using the scene editor? In either case, show your setups for the scenes. Scene Editor from the property inspector, code from the... well, code. The good news... this is absolutely solvable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, I didn't set the scene mode. I looked this problem up and I finally found the solution. Here's the code:

```
if startBTN.containsPoint(location) {

            var gameScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
            var transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.8)
            gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
            self.scene!.view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)

        }
```

I had put the gamescene file and transition, but didn't add the scalemode to it.